# copy the all line only if match python

Tags: python

trying to copy the all line from source file to created file when there is a match to spcific word "dsm".

the system is create the file but write only the last item in the list :

the code :

```
path = input(r'enter the path here : ')
path = path.replace('"', '')
SN = input(r'enter the SN :')

txt = '.log'
search = 'dsm'
Match = []

SN = SN+txt
path_and_SN = path + '\\'+SN
path_with_librealsens = path + '\\' + '1.log'

with open(path_with_librealsens, 'r') as file_open:
    for line in file_open:
        each_line = file_open.readlines()
        for eh in each_line:
            if search in eh:
                Match.append(eh.strip())

for i in Match:
    print(i)
    with open(path_and_SN, 'w') as new_sn:
        new_sn.write(i)
        new_sn.close()
```

printing :

dsm 4
dsm 5
dsm 6
dsm 7
dsm8

the file with the create text :
dsm8

it work but only write the last item in the list. please someone help !!!! :(:(

Answer (score 1):

Each time you open the file with the 'w' mode it wipes the existing content. You either want to keep the file open while writing each line or open it with the 'a' mode instead of 'w'.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open for more information on the `open` function.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file outside the while loop:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    while loop:
       f.write(stuff)
```

Also, using `with`, you don't need to close the file.